# Выборка из базы данных выводя промежуточные заголовки

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Есть таблица в базе данных MySQL с характеристиками товаров. Как разделить запрос заголовками, например: **Экран**
Покрытие: Глянцевое.
Разрешение: 640 х 480.
**Память**
RAM: 3 Гб.
Storage: 64 Гб.
Или делать запрос с WHERE отдельно для каждого заголовка?
Но тогда получиться около 15 запросов на странице, не много ли?
Как лучше реализовать такое?
Спасибо.

```html
INSERT INTO `goods_props_new` (`id`, `good_id`, `prop`, `value`, `kategor`, `compare`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'Серия:', 'Q950T', 'head', 0),
(2, 1, 'Модель:', 'QE65Q950T', 'head', 0),
(3, 1, 'Год модели:', '2020', 'head', 1),
(4, 1, 'Разрешение:', '7680 x 4320 px 8K', 'head', 0),
(5, 1, 'Другие<br /> названия<br /> модели:', 'нет данных', 'head', 0),
(6, 1, 'Диагональ:', '64.5\"', 'display', 1),
(7, 1, 'Варианты<br /> диагоналей:', '65\" 75\" 85\"', 'display', 1),
(8, 1, 'Тип матрицы:', 'MVA', 'display', 1),
(9, 1, 'Битность<br /> матрицы:', '10 bit', 'display', 1),
(10, 1, 'FRC:', 'нет', 'display', 1),
(11, 1, 'Разрешение<br /> экрана:', '7680 x 4320 px<br /> 8K', 'display', 1),
(12, 1, 'HDR:', 'HDR10<br /> HDR10+<br /> Quantum HDR 3000<br /> HLG', 'display', 1),
(13, 1, 'Частота<br /> обновления:', '40 Гц - 120 Гц', 'display', 1),
(14, 1, 'Входная<br /> задержка:', '24 мс', 'display', 1),
(15, 1, 'Миним.<br /> время отклика:', 'нет данных', 'display', 1),
(16, 1, 'Среднее<br /> время отклика:', 'нет данных', 'display', 1),
(17, 1, 'Подсветка:', 'Direct LED<br /> Full-Array Local Dimming', 'display', 1),
(18, 1, 'Яркость:', 'нет данных', 'display', 1),
(19, 1, 'Макс.<br /> яркость:', '3000 кд/м&sup2;', 'display', 1),
(20, 1, 'Статический<br />контраст:', '5000 : 1', 'display', 1),
(21, 1, 'Динамический<br />контраст:', 'нет данных', 'display', 1),
(22, 1, 'DCI P3:', '100 %', 'display', 1),
(23, 1, 'Rec. 2020:', 'нет данных', 'display', 1),
(24, 1, 'Отображ.<br /> цвета:', '1073741824<br />30 bit', 'display', 1),
(25, 1, 'Цветовая<br /> модель:', 'RGB', 'display', 1),
(26, 1, 'Углы обзора<br /> (верт./гор.):', '178&deg; / 178&deg;', 'display', 0),
(27, 1, 'Соотношение<br /> сторон:', '16:9<br /> 1.778:1', 'display', 0),
(28, 1, 'Площадь<br /> экрана:', '98,36 %', 'display', 1),
(29, 1, 'Ширина<br /> экрана:', '142,848 см', 'display', 1),
(30, 1, 'Высота<br /> экрана:', '80,352 см', 'display', 1),
(31, 1, 'Шаг пикселя:', '0.186 мм', 'display', 1),
(32, 1, 'Плотность<br /> пикселей:', '53 ppcm (пиксели на см.)<br /> 136 ppi (пиксели на дюйм)', 'display', 1),
(33, 1, 'Покрытие<br /> экрана:', 'Матовое<br /> Антибликовое', 'display', 1),
(34, 1, 'Технология<br /> интерполяц.:', 'Picture Quality Index', 'interpol', 1),
(35, 1, 'Значение<br /> интерполяц.:', '4700', 'interpol', 1),
(36, 1, 'Единица<br /> измерения:', 'PQI', 'interpol', 0),
(37, 1, 'ТВ-тюнер:', 'Аналоговый (NTSC/PAL/SECAM)<br /> DVB-T<br /> DVB-T2<br /> DVB-T2 HD<br /> DVB-S<br /> DVB-S2<br /> DVB-C', 'tuner', 1),
(38, 1, 'Название<br /> процессора<br /> изображения:', 'нет данных', 'proz', 1),
(39, 1, 'Центральный<br /> процессор:', 'ARM Cortex-A73', 'proz', 1),
(40, 1, 'Ядра<br /> центрального<br /> процессора:', '4', 'proz', 1),
(41, 1, 'Частота<br /> центрального<br /> процессора:', 'нет данных', 'proz', 1),
(42, 1, 'Графический<br /> процессор:', 'ARM Mali-G52', 'proz', 1),
(43, 1, 'Ядра<br /> графического<br /> процессора:', 'нет данных', 'proz', 1),
(44, 1, 'Частота<br /> графического<br /> процессора:', 'нет данных', 'proz', 1),
(45, 1, 'RAM (Объем<br /> оперативной<br /> памяти):', 'нет данных', 'proz', 1),
(46, 1, 'Объем<br /> встроенной<br /> памяти:', 'нет данных', 'proz', 1),
(47, 1, 'Операц.<br /> система:', 'Tizen 5.5', 'proz', 1),
(48, 1, 'Динамики:', '4 x 7.5 Вт<br /> 2 x 10 Вт', 'zvuk', 1),
(49, 1, 'Сабвуфер:', '2 x 10 Вт', 'zvuk', 1),
(50, 1, 'Аудио<br /> технологии:', '4.2.2 CH<br />Object Tracking Sound+<br />Active Voice Amplifier<br />Adaptive Sound+<br />Q Symphony<br />Dolby Digital Plus', 'zvuk', 0),
(51, 1, 'Ширина без<br /> подставки:', '143.31 см', 'razmer', 1),
(52, 1, 'Ширина с<br /> подставкой:', '143.31 см', 'razmer', 1),
(53, 1, 'Высота без<br /> подставки:', '81.43 см', 'razmer', 1),
(54, 1, 'Высота с<br /> подставкой:', '88.11 см', 'razmer', 1),
(55, 1, 'Глубина без<br /> подставки:', '1.5 см (15 мм)', 'razmer', 1),
(56, 1, 'Глубина с<br /> подставкой:', '26.19 см', 'razmer', 1),
(57, 1, 'Цвет:', 'Stainless Steel', 'razmer', 1),
(58, 1, 'Вес без<br /> подставки:', '26.5 кг', 'razmer', 1),
(59, 1, 'Вес с<br /> подставкой:', '32.1 кг', 'razmer', 1),
(60, 1, 'Напряжение:', '220-240 В', 'energo', 1),
(61, 1, 'Частота<br /> переменного<br /> тока:', '50-60 Гц', 'energo', 1),
(62, 1, 'Энергопотребление<br /> в режиме<br /> ожидания:', '0.5 Вт', 'energo', 0),
(63, 1, 'Среднее<br /> энергопотр.:', '344 Вт', 'energo', 1),
(64, 1, 'Макс.<br /> энергопотр.:', 'нет данных', 'energo', 1),
(65, 1, 'Годовое<br /> энергопотр.:', 'нет данных', 'energo', 1),
(66, 1, 'Класс<br /> энергоэф.:', 'D', 'energo', 1),
(67, 1, 'VESA:', 'да<br />400 x 300 мм', 'ergonomic', 1),
(68, 1, 'Съемная<br /> подставка:', 'да', 'ergonomic', 1),
(69, 1, 'Сеть:', 'LAN<br />Wi-Fi<br />Wi-Fi Direct<br />Bluetooth 4.2<br />DLNA', 'network', 1),
(70, 1, 'Подключ.:', '3 x USB 2.0<br />3 x HDMI 2.0<br />\r\n    1 x HDMI 2.1<br />1 x Ethernet (RJ45)<br />1 x Satellite In (Main, F-type)<br />1 x Satellite In (Sub, F-type)<br />1 x Optical Audio Out<br />1 x CI+ 1.4<br />1 x Antenna (RF)', 'network', 1),
(71, 1, 'Функции и<br /> технологии:', 'Quantum Processor 8K<br />8K AI Upscaling<br />Dynamic Black EQ<br />Digital Clean View<br />ConnectShare<br />Contrast Enhancer<br />Picture-in-Picture<br />Ultimate 8K Dimming Pro<br />Light sensor<br />Bixby<br />Google Assistant<br />Full LED Local Dimming Platinum<br />Apple AirPlay 2.0<br />SmartThings<br />Multi View<br />Filmmaker Mode<br />Multiroom Link<br />Auto Motion Plus<br />Quantum Dot Color<br />AMD FreeSync Premium<br />Real Game Enhancer+<br />Alexa<br />Ultra Viewing Angle<br />Ambient Mode+<br />PVR via USB<br />One Connect<br />Voice command<br />Game Motion Plus<br />Adaptive Picture', 'function', 0),
(72, 1, 'Аксессуары:', 'Пульт - Smart remote control - TM2090C', 'aksesuar', 1),
(73, 1, 'Плюсы::', 'Отличные цвета, контраст и яркость.<br /> Хорошая система масштабирования.<br />Технология \"Ultra Viewing Angle\" (Технология широкоугольного обзора).<br />Технология \"Samsung Object Tracking Sound\" (OTS +).', 'plusminus', 1),
(74, 1, 'Минусы:', 'Высокое время отклика (24 мс).<br />Отсутствие HDR Dolby Vision.<br />Отсутствие 8K контента.', 'plusminus', 1),
(75, 2, 'Серия:', 'W9', 'head', 0),
(76, 2, 'Модель:', 'OLED65W9PLA', 'head', 0),
(77, 2, 'Год модели:', '2019', 'head', 1),
(78, 2, 'Разрешение:', '3840 x 2160 px<br /> 4K<br /> Ultra HD', 'head', 0),
(79, 2, 'Другие<br /> названия<br /> модели:', 'нет данных', 'head', 0),
(80, 2, 'Диагональ:', '64.5\"', 'display', 1),
(81, 2, 'Варианты<br /> диагоналей:', '65\" 77\"', 'display', 1),
(82, 2, 'Тип матрицы:', 'OLED', 'display', 1),
(83, 2, 'Битность<br /> матрицы:', '10 bit', 'display', 1),
(84, 2, 'FRC:', 'нет', 'display', 1),
(85, 2, 'Разрешение<br /> экрана:', '3840 x 2160 px<br /> 4K<br /> Ultra HD', 'display', 1),
(86, 2, 'HDR:', 'HDR10<br /> HLG<br /> Dolby Vision', 'display', 1),
(87, 2, 'Частота<br /> обновления:', '120 Гц', 'display', 1),
(88, 2, 'Входная<br /> задержка:', 'нет данных', 'display', 1),
(89, 2, 'Миним.<br /> время отклика:', '1 мс', 'display', 1),
(90, 2, 'Среднее<br /> время отклика:', 'нет данных', 'display', 1),
(91, 2, 'Подсветка:', '-', 'display', 1),
(92, 2, 'Яркость:', 'нет данных', 'display', 1),
(93, 2, 'Макс.<br /> яркость:', 'нет данных', 'display', 1),
(94, 2, 'Статический<br />контраст:', 'нет данных', 'display', 1),
(95, 2, 'Динамический<br />контраст:', 'нет данных', 'display', 1),
(96, 2, 'DCI P3:', 'нет данных', 'display', 1),
(97, 2, 'Rec. 2020:', 'нет данных', 'display', 1),
(98, 2, 'Отображ.<br /> цвета:', '1073741824<br />30 bit', 'display', 1),
(99, 2, 'Цветовая<br /> модель:', 'WRGB', 'display', 1),
(100, 2, 'Углы обзора<br /> (верт./гор.):', '178&deg; / 178&deg;', 'display', 0),
(101, 2, 'Соотношение<br /> сторон:', '16:9<br /> 1.778:1', 'display', 0),
(102, 2, 'Площадь<br /> экрана:', '96,45 %', 'display', 1),
(103, 2, 'Ширина<br /> экрана:', '142.851 см', 'display', 1),
(104, 2, 'Высота<br /> экрана:', '80.354 см', 'display', 1),
(105, 2, 'Шаг пикселя:', '0.372 мм', 'display', 1),
(106, 2, 'Плотность<br /> пикселей:', '26 ppcm (пиксели на см.)<br /> 68 ppi (пиксели на дюйм)', 'display', 1),
(107, 2, 'Покрытие<br /> экрана:', 'нет данных', 'display', 1),
(108, 2, 'Технология<br /> интерполяц.:', '-', 'interpol', 1),
(109, 2, 'Значение<br /> интерполяц.:', '-', 'interpol', 1),
(110, 2, 'Единица<br /> измерения:', '-', 'interpol', 0),
(111, 2, 'ТВ-тюнер:', 'Аналоговый (NTSC/PAL/SECAM)<br /> DVB-T<br /> DVB-T2<br /> DVB-S<br /> DVB-S2<br /> DVB-C', 'tuner', 1),
(112, 2, 'Название<br /> процессора<br /> изображения:', '&alpha;9 Gen 2 Intelligent Processor', 'proz', 1),
(113, 2, 'Центральный<br /> процессор:', 'нет данных', 'proz', 1),
(114, 2, 'Ядра<br /> центрального<br /> процессора:', '4', 'proz', 1),
(115, 2, 'Частота<br /> центрального<br /> процессора:', 'нет данных', 'proz', 1),
(116, 2, 'Графический<br /> процессор:', 'нет данных', 'proz', 1),
(117, 2, 'Ядра<br /> графического<br /> процессора:', '2', 'proz', 1),
(118, 2, 'Частота<br /> графического<br /> процессора:', 'нет данных', 'proz', 1),
(119, 2, 'RAM (Объем<br /> оперативной<br /> памяти):', '3 Гб', 'proz', 1),
(120, 2, 'Объем<br /> встроенной<br /> памяти:', '8 Гб', 'proz', 1),
(121, 2, 'Операц.<br /> система:', 'webOS 4.5', 'proz', 1),
(122, 2, 'Динамики:', '2 x 10 Вт<br /> 2 x 10 Вт', 'zvuk', 1),
(123, 2, 'Сабвуфер:', '2 x 10 Вт', 'zvuk', 1),
(124, 2, 'Аудио<br /> технологии:', 'Dolby Atmos<br />DTS Decoder DTS-HD<br />4.2 Ch<br />Wireless Sound Sync', 'zvuk', 0),
(125, 2, 'Ширина без<br /> подставки:', '144.6 см', 'razmer', 1),
(126, 2, 'Ширина с<br /> подставкой:', '-', 'razmer', 1),
(127, 2, 'Высота без<br /> подставки:', '82.3 см', 'razmer', 1),
(128, 2, 'Высота с<br /> подставкой:', '-', 'razmer', 1),
(129, 2, 'Глубина без<br /> подставки:', '0.385 см (3.85 мм)', 'razmer', 1),
(130, 2, 'Глубина с<br /> подставкой:', '-', 'razmer', 1),
(131, 2, 'Цвет:', 'Черный', 'razmer', 1),
(132, 2, 'Вес без<br /> подставки:', 'нет данных', 'razmer', 1),
(133, 2, 'Вес с<br /> подставкой:', '-', 'razmer', 1),
(134, 2, 'Напряжение:', '220-240 В', 'energo', 1),
(135, 2, 'Частота<br /> переменного<br /> тока:', '50-60 Гц', 'energo', 1),
(136, 2, 'Энергопотребление<br /> в режиме<br /> ожидания:', '0.5 Вт', 'energo', 0),
(137, 2, 'Среднее<br /> энергопотр.:', '154 Вт', 'energo', 1),
(138, 2, 'Макс.<br /> энергопотр.:', 'нет данных', 'energo', 1),
(139, 2, 'Годовое<br /> энергопотр.:', 'нет данных', 'energo', 1),
(140, 2, 'Класс<br /> энергоэф.:', 'A', 'energo', 1),
(141, 2, 'VESA:', 'нет', 'ergonomic', 1),
(142, 2, 'Съемная<br /> подставка:', 'нет', 'ergonomic', 1),
(143, 2, 'Сеть:', 'LAN<br />Wi-Fi<br />Wi-Fi Direct<br />Bluetooth 5.0<br />DLNA', 'network', 1),
(144, 2, 'Подключ.:', '3 x USB 2.0<br />4 x HDMI 2.1<br />1 x Ethernet (RJ45)<br />1 x Satellite In (F-type)<br />1 x Optical Audio Out<br />1 x AV Composite In (3.5 mm jack)<br />1 x CI+ 1.4<br />1 x Antenna (RF)', 'network', 1),
(145, 2, 'Функции и<br /> технологии:', 'Voice command<br />True Color Accuracy Pro<br />Pixel Level Dimming<br />Perfect Black Panel<br />Object Depth Enhancer<br />Infinite Contrast<br />HDR Dynamic Tone Mapping Pro<br />Frequency Based Sharpness Enhancer<br />Advanced Color Enhancer<br />4K Cinema HDR<br />4-step noise reduction<br />4K Upscaler<br />Clear Voice III<br />Google Assistant<br />LG ThinQ AI<br />Oled Motion<br />Picture-on-Wall<br />PVR<br />ULTRA Luminance Pro', 'function', 0),
(146, 2, 'Аксессуары:', 'Пульт - Magic remote MR19<br />3.5 mm composite adapter<br />Батарейки AA x 2 шт.', 'aksesuar', 1),
(147, 2, 'Плюсы::', 'Качество изображения,<br /> идеальный черный цвет,<br /> контраст,<br /> дизайн,<br /> функциональность', 'plusminus', 1),
(148, 2, 'Минусы:', 'Риск выгорания пикселей', 'plusminus', 1);
```

```html
CREATE TABLE `goods_props_new` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `good_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `prop` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `value` text NOT NULL,
  `kategor` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `compare` tinyint(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Теперь нужно бы сформировать вопрос так, чтобы остальные поняли, что это всё значит в вашей голове

Comment: т.к. неизвестно, как устроена база, то и не получится дать разумный совет. Если там все характеристики одним списком, это одно, если разделены по категорями, это другое, если это просто набор текста, то третье, итд.

Comment: Кнопкой "править" добавьте в текст вопроса структуру таблицы в виде `create table ...` и данные в виде `insert into ...` и результат, который для этих данных вы хотите получить.

Comment: *Как разделить запрос заголовками, например: Экран Покрытие: Глянцевое. Разрешение: 640 х 480. Память RAM: 3 Гб. Storage: 64 Гб.* Судя по приведённым данным, Вы хотите поделить записи для товара на группы по полю `kategor`? ибо Вы пишете *Экран*, *Покрытие: Глянцевое.* - но в таблице и слов-то таких нет... Думаю, требуется дополнительная таблица, которая расшифровывает наименования категорий и задаёт для них относительное расположение.

Comment: Ему нужна тупая группировка по "kategor". То есть сортировать по категории ну и при выводе стандартный алгоритм с запоминанием предыдущего.

Comment: Да, я хочу поделить записи для товара на группы по полю kategor.

Comment: Слова Экран и Память где хранятся?

Comment: Нигде, я просто не знаю как такое сделать.

Comment: Надо сделать отдельную таблицу в БД, в которой должны лежать названия категорий. а в поле kategor писать ид из этой таблицы. и при запросе использовать джойн. но это потом. пока можно сделать с этими тарабарскими razmer и proz

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то сделайте

```
SELECT * FROM 'goods_props_new' WHERE 'good_id' = 1
```

и получите массив нужных вам данных.
Затем используйте [array_search](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-search.php) с интересующей характеристикой в качестве аргумента.

Либо, что наверное, будет более правильным - разбейте свойства на отдельные поля, будет проще работать.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ.  Не могу разобраться с array_search, как я могу его использовать в моем случае? Если Вам не трудно, можно маленький пример?

Comment: никак. здесь не нужен никакой array_search

Comment: А как лучше реализовать такое?

Comment: Пример дать не могу, т.к. я не php-шник. Это лишь предположение в рамках конкретного вопроса, хотя это решение мне не кажется рациональным. Тут сама БД неправильно построена.

Comment: "это не ответ а предположение, которое кажется мне неправильным". "языка не знаю но берусь отвечать на вопросы по нему". Вот это я называю словом "логика"